# Rename all files in order in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following files:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

When I remove `2.jpg`, I want `3.jpg` to become `2.jpg` and `4.jpg` to become `3.jpg`

I tried a for loop with the `rename` function, but it does not seem to work:

```
for($a = $i;$a < $filecount;$a ++)
{
    rename('photo/'.($a+1).'.jpg', 'photo/'.   ($a).'.jpg');
}
```

Where `$i` is the number of the photo I just deleted.

Comment: Do you mean you delete them, then try to rename them? You can't delete the photo first, you just have to rename it? What are you deleting?

Comment: No i am deleting a file, and then i want to rename the rest of the files, otherwise i have this gap. If i have like 1,2,3,4 and i delete 2, i have 1,3,4 and it supposed to be 1,2,3

Comment: @1ntello Why would you want to do this? I can't think of a reason, if I'm honest.

Comment: I have pictures i need to upload, and i am uploading them as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. There are descriptions added to those photo's, which are added in a text file. Now the first rule in the text file matches picture number 1. and so on. so when i remove 2, the rest has to change name, other wise the descriptions are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List all files, sorted by name:

```
$files = glob('../photos/*');
```

Foreach file, rename it if necessary:

```
foreach($files as $i => $name) {
    $newname = sprintf('../photos/%d.jpg', $i+1);
    if ($newname != $name) {
        rename($name, $newname);
    }
}
```

Comment: where * is the path to the folder? could you add some description?.

Comment: both of you should take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: `*` means *all files in current folder*

Comment: Yeah but what if my pictures are in another folder. I have index.php which basically handles the delete and stuff, but my pictures are in ../photo/

Comment: Now when i have 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, and i remove 1. It renames the 0 to 1, but the 2 has to become the one.

Comment: That's because in your question the files started with 1. Just remove the +1 in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the file you don't longer need and than rename all files that remain in the folder, starting with one. Like:

```
<?php
  $fileToRemove= '3.jpg';
  unlink($fileToRemove);

  $cnt = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            rename($file, ++$cnt+".jpg");
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
?>
```

This way, you are always sure that the sequence is correct. If you have a lot of files, you can of cource start renaming from the number of the file you are deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I would have do it this way:

```
echo "<pre>";
$files = array('file1.jpg', 'file5.jpg', 'file7.jpg', 'file9.jpg');

function removeElement($array, $id){
    $clone = $array; // we clone the array for naming usage
    $return = array(); // the array returned for testing purposes
    $j = 0;
    foreach($array as $num => $file){ // loop in the elements
        if($file != $id){ // check if the current file is not the element we want to remove 
            if($num == $j){ // if current element and '$j' are the same we do not need to rename that file
                $return[] = "// @rename('".$file."', '".$file."'); -- do not rename";
            } else { // if previously we have removed the file '$id' then '$j' should be -1 and we rename the file with the next one stored in '$clone' array
                $return[] = "@rename('".$file."', '".$clone[($num-1)]."'); // rename";
            }
        } else { // this is for the file we need to remove, we also -1 current '$j'
            $j--;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    return $return;
}

print_r(removeElement($files, 'file5.jpg'));
```

it seems rudimentary, but it works and is easy to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
$filecount = 5;
$i = 2;

unlink('photo/'. $i . '.jpg');
for($i; $i < $filecount; $i++) {
    rename('photo/'. ($i+1) .'.jpg', 'photo/'. $i . '.jpg');
}
die;
```