# Rename files in PHP

Tags: php

How do I rename files by appending .jpg to the name. The files have no extensions as shown in the screenshot. But I would like to add .jpg to each one - is there a php function for doing this sort of bulk renameing?

http://www.jroller.com/sennheiserheadphones/resource/imagename.jpg

Comment: Why would you want to use PHP?

Comment: There is, and it's called [`rename`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php). Who knew?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Rename+files+in+PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename all files in order in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388623/rename-all-files-in-order-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(glob("*") as $f) rename($f,$f.".jpg");
```

Only run it one time, though, because if you run it again you'll get `1734.jpg.jpg` and suchlike.

Comment: Thanks for this - it worked like magic. That saved me hours of manually renaming them. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use rename, per:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

If the files are in a directory:

```
$dir = opendir('directory containing files');

// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{

        rename($file, $file.".jpg");

}

// close the directory handle
closedir($dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `rename()`. Documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

note: next time google your question ;)